# JavaFX has problems with popups, for example Combobox, by using in Swing

Tags: java, swing, combobox, scroll, javafx

I have tried to use `JavaFX` in a `Swing` application using `JFXPanel` as wrapper for `Scene`, but I was confronted by the following difficulties: all of the popups that have the ability to scroll over long lists - for example comboboxes - cannot be properly controlled.

My sample code:

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SwingDialog extends JDialog {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        final SwingDialog dialog = new SwingDialog();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    public SwingDialog(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(new Dimension(250, 250));
        final JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
        for (int i = 0; i< 101; i++){
            combo.addItem("text" + i);
        }
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 300));
        panel.add(combo);
        panel.add(createJFXPanel());
        final JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(panel);
        getContentPane().add(scroll);
    }

    private JFXPanel createJFXPanel(){
        final JFXPanel panel = new JFXPanel();
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final HBox hbox = new HBox();
                final ComboBox combo = new ComboBox();
                for (int i = 0; i< 101; i++){
                    combo.getItems().add("text" + i);
                }
                hbox.getChildren().add(combo);
                final Scene scene = new Scene(hbox);
                panel.setScene(scene);
            };
        });
        return panel;
    }
}
```

There is the `JDialog` with `JPanel` inside the `JScrollPane` with two comboboxes: the first is a `JComboBox` and the second is a `JavaFX` ComboBox inside the `JFXPanel`.
The `JComboBox` works properly, but the `JavaFX` ComboBox cannot scroll with mouse wheel. It seems that instead of scrolling itself, the mouse wheel scrolls by the `JScrollPane` with owner `JPanel` (see screenshot below).

[image: Behavior on Scroll]

Thanks very much in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: This is a know bug and it was fixed in JavaFX 8. Please try it out. It could be downloaded from https://jdk8.java.net

Comment: Thanks, the actual version jdk-8-fcs-bin-b129-windows-x64-07_feb_2014 solves only the problem by mouse wheel scrolling inside the JavaFX ComboBox, but You can see again, that its popup (scrollpane) passes the bounds of the dialog and the worst is, that when You open popup of JavaFX ComboBox and scroll in the JScrollPane of the dialog, than the popup of JavaFX ComboBox begins to "fly". It was succeed several times (not stable) to close the dialog and the popup of JavaFX ComboBox was staying to "fly" without any dialog.

Comment: So, the newest research - the actual version JavaFX 8 beta 129 has some more problems
1) When I open popup list of JavaFX combobox, than I can click neither on the JPanel nor on JScrollPane, but I can move the JDialog away and the popup list stays "flying" out of the JDialog.

Comment: 2) We are developing a SWING-application and going to use JavaFX for rebuilding of our SWING-project, and for a start as prototype to build a ribbon-toolbar inside SWING. The application is using also as RCP-plug-in by Eclipse and the worst behavior is, when the application is opened many times in plug-in multi-windows environment - the combobox from the first instance has only the problem above, but the same combobox from other instances get location at the first combobox independently, where the owner window is located...They are flying nearby the first started window.

Comment: So, I can open all of comboboxes in all of applications and move their windows away, but popups of comboboxes remain "seated". If I open popups of comboboxes by moved windows again - the popups have previous locations immediately! It seems horrible! Unfortunately I cannot show screenshots here.

So, JavaFX developers confirm the problem, but when it will be resolved they don’t know. 

What a pity, that we cannot show a prototype for customers with such errors, and we cannot use JavaFX for our rebuilding now, obvious we need other technologies...

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary solution to show my prototype to customers I have made so:

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SwingDialog extends JFrame { //or JDialog
    public static void main(String[] args){
        final SwingDialog dialog = new SwingDialog();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    public SwingDialog(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(new Dimension(250, 250));
        final JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
        for (int i = 0; i< 101; i++){
            combo.addItem("text" + i);
        }
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 0,0,0));
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 300));
        panel.add(combo);
        panel.add(createJFXPanel());
        final JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(panel);
        getContentPane().add(scroll);
    }

    private JFXPanel createJFXPanel(){
        final JFXPanelEx panel = new JFXPanelEx();
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final VBox vbox = new VBox();
                final ComboBox combo = new ComboBox();
                for (int i = 0; i< 101; i++){
                    combo.getItems().add("text" + i);
                }
                vbox.getChildren().addAll(combo);
                final Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
                panel.setScene(scene);
            };
        });
        return panel;
    }

    private class JFXPanelEx extends JFXPanel {
        public JFXPanelEx(){
            addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                    hidePopUps();
                }
            });
        }

        private ComponentListener componentListener;

        @Override
        public void removeNotify() {
            super.removeNotify();
            final Component parent = SwingUtilities.getRoot(this);
            if (parent != null){
                parent.removeComponentListener(componentListener);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            final Component parent = SwingUtilities.getRoot(this);
            componentListener = new ComponentAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
                    hidePopUps();
                    processComponentEvent(new ComponentEvent(JFXPanelEx.this, ComponentEvent.COMPONENT_MOVED));
                }

                @Override
                public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                    hidePopUps();
                    processComponentEvent(new ComponentEvent(JFXPanelEx.this, ComponentEvent.COMPONENT_RESIZED));
                    processComponentEvent(new ComponentEvent(JFXPanelEx.this, ComponentEvent.COMPONENT_MOVED)); //is important!!!
                }
            };
            parent.addComponentListener(componentListener);
        }

        private void hidePopUps(){
            final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    hidePopUpsImpl();
                }
            };
            if (Platform.isFxApplicationThread()){
                runnable.run();
            } else {
                Platform.runLater(runnable);
            }
        }

        private void hidePopUpsImpl(){
            if (getScene() != null && getScene().getRoot() != null){
                for (final Node node : getScene().getRoot().getChildrenUnmodifiable()){ //JavaFX need interfaces!!!
                    final ComboBox combo = (ComboBox)node;
                    if (combo.isShowing()){ //JavaFX need interfaces!!!
                        combo.hide();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In Eclispe multi-windows RCP-environment I post these events (REZISED and MODEV) from Shell-Container (Composite) to my frame or dialog.
Therefore my JFXPanelEx can catch they too. 
To fire COMPONENT_MOVED by COMPONENT_REZISED is important!!! Otherwise popups don't get an actual location after resizing of many windows inside Shell-Container.
It seems, that popup will be opened with old location, so there where is no window.

It is a patch, but I hope, that JavaFX doesn't have such problems soon, otherwise it seems useless.